# Como extrair essa informação em uma string?

Tags: php

Abaixo segue uma string de saída gerada pelo ffmpeg referente algum arquivo de vídeo:

> Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 ...
>
> Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: mp3 ...
>
> Stream #0:2(por): Subtitle ...

Na maior parte dos casos o ffmpeg oferece uma função para rastrear as streams que desejo converter através do -map e o idioma, mas em alguns arquivos de vídeo não é possível obter tal mapeamento através do idioma, e é por isso que quero usar PHP para rastrear a stream que desejo pelo número e não pelo idioma.

Como posso com PHP obter as chaves de stream do vídeo `0:0`, audio `0:1` e da legenda `0:2`, sabendo que estes podem trocar de posição e até mesmo de idioma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `preg_match_all`, assim:

```
<?php

$resposta = 'Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 ...
Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: mp3 ...
Stream #0:2(por): Subtitle ...';

if (preg_match_all('/Stream\s[#](\d+:\d+)\((\w+)\):\s(\w+)[ :]+(\w+|)/i', $resposta, $output) == 0) {
    echo 'Nenhuma informação encontrada';
} else {
    print_r($output);
}
```

Então basta manipular o `array`, veja o resultado no ideone: https://ideone.com/T89v4K.

**Editado**

Consegui criar um exemplo mais fácil de usar, leia as descrições:

```
<?php
function extrairDados($dados) {
    if (preg_match_all('/Stream\s[#](\d+:\d+)(\(\w+\))?:(\s\w+|)[ :]+(\w+|)/i', $dados, $output) == 0) {
        echo 'Nenhuma informação encontrada', PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $reorganizado = array(); //Array que terá o resultado final

        //Chaves que serão usadas para tornar mais intuitivo o que é cada item
        $chaves = array(
            'tempo',
            'idioma',
            'formato',
            'codec'
        );

        //Remove o primeiro item do array gerado pelo preg_match_all, ele não é necessário
        array_shift($output);

        //Conta o total de itens
        $y = count($output);

        for ($x = 0; $x < $y; $x++) {
            $item = $output[$x]; //Pega o item atual
            $chave = $chaves[$x]; //Pega a chave atual para identificar no array
            $j = count($item); //Conta "propriedades" do item

            for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {

                //Se não existir o sub-array irá gerar
                if (isset($reorganizado[$i]) === false) {
                    $reorganizado[$i] = array();
                }

                $str = trim($item[$i]); //Remove espaços em branco
                $str = trim($str, '('); //Remove ( das extremidades
                $str = trim($str, ')'); //Remove ) das extremidades

                //Salva o item no array chave correspondente
                $reorganizado[$i][$chave] = $str;
            }
        }

        //Exibe o array
        return $reorganizado;
    }

    return false;
}
```

E para usar basta fazer assim:

```
$resposta = 'Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 ...
Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: mp3 ...
Stream #0:2(por): Subtitle ...';

$dados = extrairDados($resposta);

if ($dados) {
    foreach ($dados as $item) {
        echo 'Tempo: ', $item['tempo'], PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Idioma: ', $item['idioma'], PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Formato: ', $item['formato'], PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Codec: ', $item['codec'], PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Exemplo com diferentes resultados:

```
$resposta1 = '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) ...
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ...';

$resposta2 = '    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 ...
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 ...';

$resposta3 = '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 ...
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: mp3 ...
    Stream #0:1(por): Subtitle:';

print_r(extrairDados($resposta1));
print_r(extrairDados($resposta2));
print_r(extrairDados($resposta3));
```

Exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/PsvoOk)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9aG5qc7H

Comment: Pelo visto, o erro acontece quando o idioma não é especificado, então basta definir na regex como opcional: `'/Stream\s[#](\d+:\d+)(\((\w+)\))?:\s(\w+)[ :]+(\w+|)/i'`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado segui sua sugestão e esta corrigido http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/195629/3

Comment: @LeoLetto código corrigido, pode testar, veja o exemplo no ideone https://ideone.com/PsvoOk

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vlw pela ajuda, parece servir bem para meu uso, mas antes de aplicar a meu uso real vou estudar um pouco o que você fez, pois não entendo muito sobre expressões, então quero aprender mais primeiro.

Comment: @LeoLetto este é o intuito, regex no começo é bem dificil de entender mesmo, mas depois notará como pode ser algo útil muitas vezes, desde que não use desnecessariamente. Até o/

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução muito parecida com a apresentada pelo Guilherme, mas com um pouco menos de código, pode ser implantada como:

```
if (preg_match_all('/Stream\s[#](\d+:\d+)(\(\w+\))?:(\s\w+|)[ :]+(\w+|)/i', $resposta, $output) == 0) {
    echo 'Nenhuma informação encontrada';
} else {
    print_r(array_map(null, ...$output));
}
```

Na verdade, a solução do problema é exatamente o mesmo: utilizar expressão regular para extrair os dados do texto; o que muda é apenas a maneira de agrupar esses dados utilizando a função `array_map`.

A função `array_map` recebe como primeiro parâmetro uma função de *callback*, porém, quando `null`, o próprio valor do *array* é retornado. Se passado vários *arrays*, é feito uma compactação, por assim dizer, semelhante a função `zip` nativa do Python.

> O operador `...` utilizado na chamada de `array_map` faz com que cada valor de `$output` seja passado como parâmetro. O código equivalente seria: `array_map(null, $output[0], $output[1], $output[2])`. Este operador é conhecido como [splat](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat), ele suporta `Arrays` e `Traversable` e esta disponível desde a versão *PHP 5.6*

Para a entrada:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 ...
Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: mp3 ...
Stream #0:1(por): Subtitle:
```

A saída produzida seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4
            [1] => 0:0
            [2] => (und)
            [3] =>  Video
            [4] => mpeg4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: mp3
            [1] => 0:1
            [2] => (jpn)
            [3] =>  Audio
            [4] => mp3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stream #0:1(por): Subtitle:
            [1] => 0:1
            [2] => (por)
            [3] =>  Subtitle
            [4] => 
        )

)
```

Bem semelhante à resposta gerada pelo código do Guilherme, mas com um pouco menos de linhas.

Pode ver o código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GzFm/1) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Eoc5L3).